# Custom dialog without title is messing my layout up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I am trying to create a custom dialog without the title bar and I following SO suggestion by doing the following

```
propDiag = new Dialog(this);
propDiag.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
propDiag.setContentView(R.layout.property_daig);
```

Here is a part of my xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation= "horizontal">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation= "vertical" android:layout_weight="1" >

                   //COUPLE OF buttons

        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.5" ></View>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation= "vertical"  android:layout_weight="1"  >
                       //COUPLE OF buttons
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem that it is messing up my layout and everything gets pushed to max right and left

When I do it without the requestWindowFeature, then everything is great except for the title appearing!.

Can anyone explain and recommend a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See below code:

I don't have your background image, but just have put the icon image and execute the below code.

Also have attached the screen shot of the output.

Code:

```
 Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
             dialog.getWindow();
             dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.property_daig);

             dialog.show();

        }

    });
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this    

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.getWindow();
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

                    TextView customText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.customDialogTitletext);
                    customText.setText(text);
                    customText.setTypeface(tf);
                    Button btnOk = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk);
                    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();

                }
```

Let me know your problem is resolved or not.

Comment: I am not sure how that is related to my posted code as i dont have this ok button and title Id you mentioned. I in addition you used the same code I had by requesting window with no title feature. Plus dialog. Getwindow by itself like that does nothing

Comment: it is only possible way to delete the title in dialog. and titleId and button are in my custom dialog layout.